# Less String Interpolation not working

Tags: string, less, interpolation

Hello I have some less code and I'm trying to leverage less to get the following:

What I'm expecting:

```
@media only screen {
  #testphone {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

My code:

```
#testPhone {
  .testPhone({
    & {
      display: block;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  });
}

.testPhone( @rules ){
  .startQuery();
  .screenOnly( @myQuery );
  .create( @newQuery; @rules );
}

.create( @newQuery; @rules ){
  @{newQuery} {
    @rules();
  }
}

.screenOnly( @myQuery ){
  @newQuery: "@{myQuery} only screen";
}

.startQuery(){
  @myQuery: "@media";
}
```

What I'm getting:

```
#testPhone "@media only screen" {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

What I think is going wrong:
In the `.create` mixin when I call `@{newQuery}` to interpolate `@newQuery` variable, it isn't removing the string off of that variable.

Comment: use: `@newQuery: @{myQuery} only screen;` without qoutes, so it will be evaluated as a media query and not a string

Comment: Ahh thanks for your help. The purpose of this was to create a series of mixins that use string interpolation to chain and build a media query. Looks like its just some weird bug with using `@media` in a string https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1538. Worked fine when took out the   `@media`.

Comment: The mistake here is that you can't use *selector* interpolation to expand `@media` directive itself (as this way Less treats it as a selector but the `@media` directive is not). You can use variables for any value coming after the `@media` but the `@media` itself should appear explicitly.

Comment: Also, before writing an answer, it's also important to mention that this whole approach of concatenating `media` queries into a variable won't work for more then one item since that way you'll have to redefine `@newQuery` with its own value which is impossible in Less. So you need to rethink the whole approach anyway.

Comment: You're definitely right, I'll gonna look into different approaches at this.